# Integrate searching with Pagination in PHP5

Tags: php, database, search, pagination

I need to search details. I have written the code for searching ie, the textbox and search button is written in the homepage as well as the "search_result.php".
Pagination without searching is working well. the searching also is working without pagination.

So I guess if the search value from the homepage is stored in the session then may be  I'll get that with pagination.

If there is something more. please help me.. :(

Comment: Would you mind adding some code here? From what I understand it looks like you are setting the sql values for the pagination (i.e. limit ) wrong

Answer (score 0):

You haven't share code so am in dark what your actually doing or whats wrong.

But there is alternative.

I guess you should try: https://datatables.net/

You does not have to worry about the search results and pagination. datatables takes care of it.

Although datatable in this example fetch all records at once, that may affect on performance if your working with large no of records,

in that case go for : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Although this might be a good answer it would be good to add in the best bits from the link in your post.

Comment: thanks.. this was helpful but the real problem was with post and get method.. its clear now..

Comment: but can you help me with the best and easy way to find difference between 2 dates. 1 date from database and one as today..

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF( date_column_name, CURRENT_DATE() ) as new_column_name FROM table_name
show me thumbs up, if it works :)